# gData API - "This feed is read-only" error when adding to Google Calendar

Tags: gdata-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using **Google Apps for my domain**, and trying to enable access to the calendar on my website.

The problem is that I get `This feed is read-only` error every time I try to add an event to the calendar. Here's where I post to: <strike>[Link](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mydomain.com_oaiat5pq6l6dsfnmrodn8susvc@group.calendar.google.com/private/basic)</strike> (dead link)

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the basic feed, which according to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/reference.html#Event_feeds) is always read-only. Use a feed URL ending in `private/full` or `private/full-noattendees` instead.

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, and as part of implementing the calendar side of [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/default/sync.html) I've had some experience of working with the GData APIs, but anything I write here must be taken to be the views of a private individual rather than as official Google policy etc :)